Series expansions for finite nested roots and a related functional equation
I stumbled upon
$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4 \cdot 2}+ \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{6 \cdot 4 \cdot 2} + \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}{8 \cdot 6 \cdot 4 \cdot 2} +...  = 2 + 2\left( \sqrt{e} - \frac{ \sqrt[8]{e} \pi^2 }{2!}+ \frac{ \sqrt[32]{e} \pi^4 }{4!}- ... + (-1)^k\frac{ \sqrt[2 \cdot 4^k]{e} \pi^{2k} }{(2k)!} + ... \right)$$
and later found  a proof.
The proof is very simple (but messy) and relies on the fact
$$2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}\right) = \underbrace{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...+\sqrt{2}}}}}_\text{n - roots} ~ , $$
which is very easy to prove with the addition formulas for the cosine. Furthermore one needs a closed series expanison for the cosine function to fit everything in one equation. A sketch of the proof with $g(x):=2\cos(x)$ looks about like
\begin{eqnarray*}
    \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4 \cdot 2}+ \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{6 \cdot 4 \cdot 2} + \frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}}{8 \cdot 6 \cdot 4 \cdot 2} +...  &=& \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{g(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}})}{\prod_{k=1}^{n+1} 2k} \\
    & & = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{g(\frac{\pi}{2^n})}{2^n \cdot n!} \\
    & & = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2(-1)^k \cdot (\pi 2^{-n})^{2k}}{2^n \cdot n!\cdot (2k)!} \\
    & & = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2(-1)^k \cdot (\pi 2^{-n})^{2k}}{2^n \cdot n!\cdot (2k)!} \\
    & & = 2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-\pi^2)^k }{(2k)! } \cdot\underbrace{\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(2^{-2k-1})^{n}}{n!}}_\text{$\exp({2^{-2k-1}})-1-(2^{-2k-1})$} \\
    & & = 2\sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{\exp({2^{-2k-1}})(-\pi^2)^k }{(2k)!}  \underbrace{-2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-\pi^2)^k }{(2k)!}}_\text{$=-2\cos(\pi)=2$} -\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\frac{-\pi^2}{4})^k }{(2k)!}}_\text{$=2\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 0$} \\
    & & = 2 + 2\left( \sqrt{e} - \frac{ \sqrt[8]{e} \pi^2 }{2!}+ \frac{ \sqrt[32]{e} \pi^4 }{4!}- ... + (-1)^k\frac{ \sqrt[2 \cdot 4^k]{e} \pi^{2k} }{(2k)!} + ... \right)~.
   \end{eqnarray*}
I want construct a similar (non-trivial) example like the one given above with another number in the nested root. Of corse one could divide the eqution by $2$ and distribute the factor through the roots to gain nested roots around $1/2$, but thats just a new way to write the starting example and not really a new result. For this I tried to study the functional equation $$f(x)^2 = m + f(sx)$$ where $f$ is an entire function and $m$ and $s$ are fixed constants. I will sketch my results roughly. Then we have for every $x$ $$f(x) = \underbrace{\sqrt{m+\sqrt{m+\sqrt{m+...+\sqrt{m + f(s^n x)}}}}}_\text{n - roots} ~.$$
If $f$ is not constant and $m\neq 0$ by pircards little theorem we know that $f(z_0)=0$ for some $z_0$. Because $f(x)=0 \iff f(sx) = -m$, hence if $f$ is nowhere $0$ it is nowhere equal to $-m$. So we have  $$f\left(\frac{z_0}{s^n}\right) = \underbrace{\sqrt{m+\sqrt{m+\sqrt{m+...+\sqrt{m }}}}}_\text{n - roots}~.$$
Here I should mention that this builds on the asumption that there is canonical way of choosing the square root.
In conclusion we can construct an analog version of the example with an $m$ in the nested root iff we can find a series expansion for a solution to the functional equation (technically the solutione does not have to be an entire function, but this makes everything a lot easier).
I further noticed that the solutions to the functional equation can be represented by one function. $$Q(z,s)^2 = \frac{s^2}{4} - \frac{s}{2} + Q(sz,s)$$  with $Q'(0)=s$. Then every soluton $f$ of the functional eqation has the form $$ f(z) = Q(t \cdot z^k, s^k)$$ for an natural number $k$ and a complex number $t$. This text skips many steps but now I get to the real deal. All this is a reduction to: Can we find a "closed" expansion for $Q(z,s)$ as a power series in $z$ at expansion point $0$ for some value of $s \neq 4$ (note that $s=4$ is the cosine example above)? The natural thing to do would be a comparison of coefficients with the cauchy product.
This leads to $$Q(z,s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \beta_n(s) z^n = s\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n B_n(s) \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(s^k -1)^{-1}   $$ with $\beta_0 =s/2, \beta_1 =s, B_0 = 1/2, B_1 =1$ and for $n\ge2$ $$\beta_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{\beta_k\beta_{n-k}}{s^n-s} \qquad B_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} B_kB_{n-k}P_{k-1}^{n-2} $$ where $P_k ^n$ denotes the $q$-analog of the binomial $n \choose k$ evaluated at $q=s$. Those two series expansions are the same (hopefully). The $\beta$ version looks nicer and the $B$ version only deals with polynomials in $s$ (because $B_n(s)$ is always a polynomial in $s$). I was able to prove a few simple patterns for the polynomials like (for $n\ge1$): $$\deg B_n = \deg B_{\lfloor(n/2)\rfloor} + \deg B_{n-\lfloor(n/2)\rfloor} + (n-\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor-1)(\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor -1)$$
$$B_n(1) = (n-1)!$$
$$B_n(0) = \frac{(2n)!}{(n+1)! n!}$$
$$\cdots$$
But now I am stuck for quit a while. I can not generelise further. I can not find more reults to prove an I have not found an answer to my origanl question. So does there exist a closed formula for the $B_n$? I expect that I still worked to general... does there exist a value of $s$ such that we can write down $B_n$ without using recursion?
Any help, comments, ideas, examples etc. would be appreciated.
